nohup has no effect when called from background service?
I have a java application which is running as background service on a ubuntu system. The application is running under root account and is started/stopped via systemctl. The application has an auto-update feature. To run the update the application starts a runupdate.sh script.
public void installUpdate() {
    final List<String> cmd = List.of("sh",script.getAbsolutePath());
    final Process process = new ProcessBuilder(cmd)
                        .directory(script.getParentFile())
                        .inheritIO()
                        .start();
}

Then runupdate.sh calls dpkg with nohup
runupdate.sh
#!/bin/sh

BASEDIR=$(dirname "$0")
chmod -R +x $BASEDIR/myapplication_3.23.99_amd64.deb
nohup dpkg -i $BASEDIR/myapplication_3.23.99_amd64.deb >update.log 2>&1 &

But it looks like the update process is interrupted when the service is stopped. This is the content of update.log. (unfortunately my system is in german)
(Lese Datenbank ... 275752 Dateien und Verzeichnisse sind derzeit installiert.)
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../myapplication_3.23.99_amd64.deb ...
Removed /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/myapplication.service.

The package remains in this state:
Status: install reinstreq half-configured
When I start runupdate.sh from the terminal directy, everything works fine.
Has anyone an explanation for this behaviour or an idea how to prevent interruption of the update process?

Is your Java service program myapplication? If so, will it become an infinite loop? myapplication, call Shell, remove myapplication and then install myapplication???
Start yourself, remove yourself, install yourself?

yes, myapplication is the java application. the update procedure is only called in case an update is available. (I edited my question to make this clearer). so it's not really an infinite loop.

Enter su - xxx in Terminal, try to execute java application or runupdate.sh with user account xxx here? (xxx is the account used by your Ubuntu background service)

The nohup utility protects the program from the HUP signal. If the service is stopped with some other signal like TERM, it will not help.

Maybe you could run your background activity in something like a detached screen?

@teapot418: Thanks a lot. This sounds reasonable. Do you have a suggestion how to solve the issue? Would it to use bash and disown the process ?

@life888888: The background process already runs as root.

You can add -D=1 to dpkg flags. It will add more debugging information. You can look into documentation about other debugging options if needed.

systemctl goes to considerable effort to track and manage everything belonging to any given service.  Your best bet would probably be to move the update process into a separate, for-purpose service.

Did you by any chance use jpackage to build this application, and from a very recent JDK 17/21 or 22 (not first release, but .0.1 update)?

@DuncG yes. the installer is built with jpackage from a slightly modified version of 21+37-LTS

It is interesting you have a solution. Your problem has the indicators being a duplicate of the annoying bug JDK-8325203- though your case is first time I've seen non-Windows report. Once a jpackage app closes after launching the update installer, the installer is killed possibly before it has chance to run, and unfortunately this bug was backported to all of the current JDKs 17/21/22.

Another similar one

@DuncG thanks. this is very interesting, but a little bit different. The problem in my case was the default configuration of the service which kills all child processes.

When the service is stopped, a SIGTERM signal is send to the process and its child processes by default. As @teapot418 pointed out, nohup does not help with that signal.
The solution in my case was to change the killMode in the service configuration file to process . Now the service itself is killed, but the update script keeps running.
